# Using Python to retrieve website table data after filtering a specific date

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, calendar

I am trying to build a python script to retrieve historic wind power data from this [site](https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=actgenration/actualgeneration)

I have done sort of a similar thing before. In that case the date and relevant parameters were entered explicitly in the url address.

As you can see in the previous link, e.g. the date is selected from a calendar and it is not displayed as part of the web address.

How can I use python to select an specific date and type in an Id for the  fields `Settlement Date`and `NGC BM Unit Id` respectively?

For example:

`Settlement Date` = 2017-08-01

`NGC BM Unit Id` = ANSUW-1

I don't have a MWE because I've no clue how to proceed. I was trying to reuse code from other script I'd used to get weather data:

```
  from lxml import html
  from lxml import etree
  import urllib

  def gettabledata():

    web= urllib.urlopen("https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=actgenration/actualgeneration")
    s = web.read()  
    html = etree.HTML(s)
```

but in this case it's no that simple since the filter parameters are not passed through the url.

Thanks.

Comment: Very likely you can do it with selenium. If you want sample code then type the 'at' symbol and select my name from the drop-down menu to reply to this message. Notice that you can also arrange to download the results in the form of either an xml file or a csv, which saves parsing HTML.

Comment: @BillBell If you could help me with a sample code that would be great. I didnt try the website's download options because the idea is to get quite a few several months of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the advice I offered in the comment was genuinely awful. Shahin is right. What I would add is that you can get the result in json which is relatively easy to process. It has taken me this long to get to this point.

```
>>> import requests
>>> parameter={"flowid":"b1610","start_date":"2017-08-02","period":"*","bmu_id":"ANSUW-1"}
>>> arg = 'https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=tablegen&parameter=%s' % str(parameter).replace("'",'"').replace(' ','')
>>> r = requests.get(arg)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

The result in `r` is json which admittedly looks horrible. However, on inspection it proves to be a series of nested dictionaries. Eventually, if you burrow in you find that `'item'` is a list of 48 dictionaries from which you can easily extract whatever you might want.

```
>>> r.json()['responseBody']['responseList']['item'][0]
{'quantity': '1.414', 'marketGenerationBMUId': 'T_ANSUW-1', 'timeSeriesID': 'ELX-EMFIP-AGOG-TS-14842', 'powerSystemResourceType': 'Generation', 'resolution': 'PT30M', 'documentRevNum': '1', 'bMUnitID': 'T_ANSUW-1', 'registeredResourceEICCode': '48W00000ANSUW-1E', 'businessType': 'Production', 'settlementPeriod': '48', 'curveType': 'Sequential fixed size block', 'marketGenerationUnitEICCode': '48W00000ANSUW-1E', 'activeFlag': 'Y', 'nGCBMUnitID': 'ANSUW-1', 'processType': 'Realised', 'documentID': 'ELX-EMFIP-AGOG-17134615', 'marketGenerationNGCBMUId': 'ANSUW-1', 'settlementDate': '2017-08-02', 'documentType': 'Actual generation'}
>>> r.json()['responseBody']['responseList']['item'][47]
{'quantity': '1.088', 'marketGenerationBMUId': 'T_ANSUW-1', 'timeSeriesID': 'ELX-EMFIP-AGOG-TS-172', 'powerSystemResourceType': 'Generation', 'resolution': 'PT30M', 'documentRevNum': '1', 'bMUnitID': 'T_ANSUW-1', 'registeredResourceEICCode': '48W00000ANSUW-1E', 'businessType': 'Production', 'settlementPeriod': '1', 'curveType': 'Sequential fixed size block', 'marketGenerationUnitEICCode': '48W00000ANSUW-1E', 'activeFlag': 'Y', 'nGCBMUnitID': 'ANSUW-1', 'processType': 'Realised', 'documentID': 'ELX-EMFIP-AGOG-17134615', 'marketGenerationNGCBMUId': 'ANSUW-1', 'settlementDate': '2017-08-02', 'documentType': 'Actual generation'}
```

You can set `items` to the `'item'` dictionary and then go from there.

```
>>> items = r.json()['responseBody']['responseList']['item']
>>> items[0]['settlementPeriod']
'48'
>>> items[47]['quantity']
'1.088'
```

Addendum: In case you don't know how I was able to get that url this is it. I used the Chrome browser. I right-clicked on any element and then on 'Inspect'. Then I clicked on the 'Network' tab in the right-hand pane, then  on 'XHR'. Now I clicked on the 'View' button. As you see in the small screen view below I could just about see '?q=tablegen' in the table. I right-clicked and copied that into an editor for study.

[image: Chrome Network tab]

Answer (score 2):

I think the below script will fetch you the desired response:

```
import requests

payload = {"flowid":"b1610","start_date":"2017-08-01","period":"*","bmu_id":"ANSUW-1"}

headers={
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}

page = requests.get("https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?", params=payload, headers=headers).text

print(page)
```

Comment: You were about 13 minutes ahead of me!